# `filterKeys` and `mapValues` get executed multiple times

Tags: scala, scala-collections

When I use `filterKeys` or `mapValues` on a `Map` to create a new `Map`, the functions I've passed into these methods seems to get executed every single time I use the new `Map`. Shouldn't they only get executed once to generate the new `Map`?

In this example see how the `println`s happen multiple times.

```
// printlns happen when creating the map
scala> val myMap = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3).filterKeys { i => 
    println(s"filterKeys$i")
    i < 5
  }.mapValues { i =>
    println(s"mapValues$i")
    i + 1
  }
filterKeys1
mapValues1
filterKeys2
mapValues2
filterKeys3
mapValues3
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4)

// printlns happen again!
scala> myMap.toString()
filterKeys1
mapValues1
filterKeys2
mapValues2
filterKeys3
mapValues3
res29: String = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4)

// and again!
scala> myMap + (4 -> 5)
filterKeys1
mapValues1
filterKeys2
mapValues2
filterKeys3
mapValues3
res30: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 5)
```

I would expect the behaviour to be the same as `.map()`. The function passed to map, only gets run one for each item, and is not run again when the resulting map is used in the future:

```
// printlns happen when creating the map
scala> val myMap = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3).map { i =>
  println(s"map$i")
  i
}
map(1,1)
map(2,2)
map(3,3)
myMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)

// printlns not run again :)
scala> myMap.toString
res32: String = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

The [scaladocs for `mapValues`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#mapValues%5BW%5D(f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,W%5D) and [`filterKeys`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html#mapValues%5BW%5D(f:V=%3EW):scala.collection.immutable.Map%5BK,W%5D) both mention that they return a resulting map that wraps the original map without copying any elements. You can see in the source code that [`mapValues`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/MapLike.scala#L102) returns an instance of [`MappedValues`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/05016d9035ab9b1c866bd9f12fdd0491f1ea0cbb/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L252) which re-runs your function for every repeated `foreach`, `iterator` and `get` call.

Because this behaviour is inconsistent with `.map()`, there is ticket [SI-4776](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4776) open to either rename the methods or change their return type to make this more obvious, however the ticket has been open for a long time, so don't expect this behaviour to change soon.

Update: Since Scala 2.13 these methods have been deprecated with plans to fix in a future version:

> (Since version 2.13.0) Use .view.mapValues(f). A future version will include a strict version of this method (for now, .view.mapValues(f).toMap).

As well as the `view.mapValues(f).toMap` suggested, you can also get around this by using `transform` instead of `mapValues` and `filter` instead of `filterKeys`:

```
val myMap = Map(1 -> 1, 2 -> 2, 3 -> 3).filter { case (i, _) => 
    println(s"filterKeys$i")
    i < 5
  }.transform { (_, i) =>
    println(s"mapValues$i")
    i + 1
  }

// no printlns when the Map is used again!
myMap.toString
```

Comment: This has been also blogged about [here](http://blog.bruchez.name/2013/02/mapmap-vs-mapmapvalues.html)